# Does the "Hide ignored tags" no longer work?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

For the past two or three days, it seems that even if I have "hide ignored tags" checked in my preferences, all those questions still show up. I've noticed this on Stack Overflow - not sure if the other sites have the same thing happening.

As if that setting is being ignored - on purpose? Or is it a bug?

Comment: You can hide ignored tags? How?!

Comment: @ColonelPanic: in your settings (click on your name in the top bar on the screen, then pick "Prefs" from the top menu) you get preferences - favorite and ignored tags, and under "ignored tags", there's a "hide ignored tags" checkbox

Comment: Thanks marc! Wanted to hide those posts for ages, didn't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It still works for me. Since hiding occurs client-side, you may have some outdated JS in your cache. Try flushing your browser's cache and giving it another try. If that doesn't work, we'll have to try something else.

On which site (SO/SF/SU/Meta) did you notice this issue? What tag were you trying to hide?

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, thanks!